# Data insertion error using seeders in laravel latest version

Tags: php, laravel

i am new to laravel framework. i'm trying to insert data into a table named Users. The below error is happened

Class "Database\Seeders\DB" not found

1   C:\xampp\htdocs\newwalk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
Database\Seeders\UserTableSeeder::run()

2   C:\xampp\htdocs\newwalk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:41
Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()

Here is my UserTableSeeder.php

```
<?php
namespace Database\Seeders;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
//use DB;
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder{
/**
* Run the database seeds.
*
* @return void
*/
public function run()
{
DB::table('users')::insert(
[
'name'=>'Akhila',
'password'=>'ethan'
] );
}}
```

Comment: Add a \ in front of `DB` to break it out of the namespace. `\DB::table...`

Comment: What happens when you uncomment the `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` statement? Also, it should be `DB::table('users')->insert([ ... ])`.

Comment: showing same error when uncomment the use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Comment: when I use \ infront of DB the following error is happen.   Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() cannot be called statically

Comment: It should be `\DB::table('users')->insert(...` You can't use it doubly statically

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Database\Seeders;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\User;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
//use DB;
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
$data = [
['name' => 'akhila', 'password' => 'ethan']
];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
User::create($value);}
}
}
```

It works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).